# How to create one pooled datafile after (5) multiple imputations in order to fill in the missing values in SPSS?

Tags: spss, missing-data, multiple-imputation

I used the multiple imputation method to fill in my missing data points in a big dataset. My dataset now contains values for 5 imputations. I know there is an option to analyze with the pooled value of the 5 imputations, but how do I create a dataset with the pooled values of the multiple imputations?

Comment: Is your question about how to do this in SPSS specifically? Then this is a programming question; these are off-topic on Cross Validated and are better suited to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).